# MySql STR_TO_DATE not working in Stored Procedure

Tags: java, mysql, database, str-to-date

I want to add date from my JSP to mysql database using Servlet, if i write a query then STR_TO_DATE work properly for insertion, but if i use STR_TO_DATE in Stored Procedure it gives me "com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '11-10-2015' for column 'DATE' at row 1".

My Query is:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (DATE) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2010','%d-%m-%Y'));"
```

Any Idea?

Comment: i know but my question is why the function STR_TO_DATE is working in normal query and not in a stored Procedure????

Comment: One question mark is enough. There's no need to get crazy???????

Comment: `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2010','%d-%m-%Y');` returns `(null)`   `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2010','%d/%m/%Y');` returns `2010-01-01` your formating within STR_TO_DATE is wrong

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter within the function STR_TO_DATE is using the wrong format.
You need to use `%d/%m/%Y` instead of `%d-%m-%Y`because your date is formatted with / seperator.

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (DATE) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2010','%d/%m/%Y'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`STR_TO_DATE` requires the formatting of the strings to match:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (DATE) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2010','%d/%m/%Y'));
```

Refer to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for full details.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: Your answer is leading to a miss information about the use of a function in an insert command. It is perfect fine to use a function inside the values parameters. look it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd0d19/1

Comment: Please edit it removing that information so I can retract the downvote.